# Testing Environment for Data Science Models in Industries?

Tags: data-mining, predictive-modeling

In Software Engineering, when an application gets developed it would be pushed into the testing environment to make sure that the application is reliable and doesn't have any bugs. Mostly this will be done by another User other than the Developer.

How does it work in Data Science?

Do we have a testing Environment in industries as well before the model goes into Production?

If yes, what will a sample test case look like and will there be a separate tester or is it the developer doing different tests like Gini Test or the T-test and evaluate his results against AUC, Recall and Precision ?

Comment: You can test predictive models too, knowing the type, range, and statistical properties of the outputs. Testers might not know machine learning, so the machine learning engineer might (help) write the tests using a test data set.

Comment: @Emre Thanks for this information. But my doubt is "You Can test" or "You must test"

Comment: That's up to you. Test for things that have the potential to fail, either through user error, system error, upgrades of subcomponents, etc. The same way you would write tests for non-ML code.